# You don't have permission to access /asd on this server

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

I am using apache server version 2.4

I have installed apache to a custom location by specifying --prefix during configure.

I'm on mac os x mavericks.

I am using apache module written in c. I'm following the tutorials at the official site http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

I installed module given under mod_example.c : The code is give below

```
/* Include the required headers from httpd */
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_request.h"

/* Define prototypes of our functions in this module */
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool);
static int example_handler(request_rec *r);

/* Define our module as an entity and assign a function for registering hooks  */

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   example_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,            // Per-directory configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-directory configurations
    NULL,            // Per-server configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-server configurations
    NULL,            // Any directives we may have for httpd
    register_hooks   // Our hook registering function
};


/* register_hooks: Adds a hook to the httpd process */
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool) 
{

    /* Hook the request handler */
    ap_hook_handler(example_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

/* The handler function for our module.
 * This is where all the fun happens!
 */

static int example_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    /* First off, we need to check if this is a call for the "example" handler.
     * If it is, we accept it and do our things, it not, we simply return DECLINED,
     * and Apache will try somewhere else.
     */
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED);

    // The first thing we will do is write a simple "Hello, world!" back to the client.
    ap_rputs("Hello, world!<br/>", r);
    return OK;
}
```

I added my Set Handler as follows

```
<IfModule example_module>
    <Location /*>
        SetHandler example_module
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

when I try to access localhost/ , I get "It Works!" screen.

But when I try to access some path in localhost like localhost/asd I get the following error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /asd on this server. Server unable
>   to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Can you please help me solve this ?

Comment: the question probably need you to post your code example to get a proper analysis of your problem.

Comment: Hi dvhh, I've added the code